# LinkedList inside a LinkedList iteration in java

Tags: java, object, linked-list, comparator

Im trying to iterate a Linked List inside of a linked list but I'm not sure how to proceed with it. I'm used to using a passed parameter for what will be iterated but when I'm iterating a linked list within a linked list and plan to iterate until I hit a record that matches a passed dummy object.

Here is an example of what I’m trying to do

```
private static boolean addSongFromAlbumToAlbum(LinkedList<Album> albums1, LinkedList<Song> targetAlbum,
                                             String title){
//creating a dummy song for comparison of title parameter with arbitrary time duration.
        Song dummySong = new Song(title, 000);

        ListIterator<Album> album1ListIterator = albums1.listIterator();
        ListIterator<Song> targetAlbumListIterator = targetAlbum.listIterator();

        //nested album iterator
        ListIterator<Song> nestedAlbumInAlbum = nestedAlbum.listIterator();

        //checking whether the song with the "title" parameter entered exists in the LinkedList
        //of albums
        while(album1ListIterator.hasNext()){

            while(nestedAlbumInAlbum.hasNext()){

                //checking if current iteration has an object with same value for title as title parameter.

                Song comparisonSongToAdd = nestedAlbumInAlbum.next();
                int comparisonValue = comparisonSongToAdd.getTitle().compareTo(title);
                if(comparisonValue ==0){

                    //check whether the found object already exists in the album
                    while (targetAlbumListIterator.hasNext()){
                        SongComparator comparator = new SongComparator(); //create new comparator object to compare

                        int comparatorValue = comparator.compare(comparisonSongToAdd, targetAlbumListIterator.next());
                        if (comparatorValue == 0) {
                            System.out.println(comparisonSongToAdd + " already exists in the Album. please choose\n a different song.");
                            return false;

                        }//end if comparator

                    }//end target album while
                    targetAlbumListIterator.add(comparisonSongToAdd);

                }//end if song title found

            }//end nested album while
        }//end albums while iterator
        return true;

    }//end addSongFromAlbum method
```

///Here is the SongComparator class

```
public class SongComparator implements Comparator<Song> {

    public int compare(Song song1, Song song2){
        if(song1.getTitle() == song2.getTitle() && song1.getDurationSeconds() == song2.getDurationSeconds()){
            return 0;
        }else{
            return -1;
        }
    }

}
```

How am I supposed to iterate the LinkedList within the LinkedList of albums without a parameter? And if it requires a parameter how I’m I supposed to determine what to use for the parameter considering it will be changing with each iteration of the outer while loop.

Comment: in wath moment do you get "nestedAlbum" object?

Comment: The nested album object, which is of Song type, if found by comparing the title feild of the object with the parameter that is passed, is then saved into a variable named songToAdd.

Comment: This does not compile currently because the list iterator for nestedAlbum does not have a parameter that is passed into the iterator like the other iterators. This is the part that I'm not sure how to resolve. Also, the compareTo(title) is not working either "cant resolve method compareTo in Song"

Comment: Can you show us Song class implementing Comparator?

Comment: sure Ill post it

Comment: if getTitle() return String compare() should return song1.getTitle().compareTo(song2.getTitle()). in other hand if you want to use song1.getDurationSeconds() it should  return teh result of song1.getDurationSeconds() - song2.getDurationSeconds()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use java 8 streams,
instead of creating iterators,

in order to find whats in album 1 and album 2 use:

```
    albums1.forEach(album1Element -> {
        //keeps only what returns true in the filter.
        List<Song> listOfSongsToAdd = targetAlbum.filter(song -> song.compareTo(title)).collect(Collectors.toList);
        listOfSongsToAdd.forEach(songToAdd -> {
           ...

        });

    });
```

Comment: Thanks, I have to do some research on how to use steams I have not used them before. and see if that can solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Check below line of code. Here, `next()` returns a `Song` object and `title` is a `String` object. These both cannot be compared. You may have to call `nestedAlbumInAlbum.next()` and store the object in a `Song` reference variable and compare `song.getTitle()` with `title`.

```
int comparisonValue = nestedAlbumInAlbum.next().compareTo(title);
```

Also, you are calling `nestedAlbumInAlbum.next()` multiple times. 1 instance is above, another instance is within the `if` condition. You should restrict calling `next()` method only once for iteration. Each time when you call `nestedAlbumInAlbum.next()`, it returns the next `Song` object.

Comment: Ok, Thanks I have made the changes to the multiple occurrences of the nestedAlbumInAlbum.next() and also stored the object in a refference variable.